# What is the opposite of "idiomatic", as in idiomatic code?

Tags: antonyms

What is the opposite of "idiomatic", other than *not* idiomatic?  Is there a concise way of expressing this concept or describing such a code?

Comment: Can you explain which sense of 'idiomatic' you have in mind? Perhaps _unnatural-sounding_ is closest to an antonym for the primary meaning, but _transparent_ or _decomposable_, or _literal_ come closer to antonyms for  the other common sense.

Comment: If something is not idiomatic, then it's *unidiomatic*.

Answer (score 6):

**Unconventional** or even simply, **non-idiomatic**.

By *idiomatic*, you [refer to code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84102/what-is-idiomatic-code) that conforms to the standards of the language. If you are using non-conventional code, you do not fully conform to the language but instead somehow write a code to accomplish the task at hand.

In technical circles, it is safe to stick to *non-idiomatic*, because in that case, people knowing the technical definition of *idiomatic* will be clear about the intention.

Comment: not sure you need *non-idiomatic* when *unidiomatic* will do.

Answer (score 6):

*Idiosyncratic* derives from the same Greek roots as *idiomatic* but has an opposite connotation. Both refer to peculiarity, but where [*idiom*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/idiom) is a usage that has become customary in a community, [*idiosyncrasy*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/idiosyncrasy) is an individual quirk.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand your question, you are looking for a term that describes code that would be implemented in such a way that few programmers would recognize.

A programming term that is used is *anti-pattern*, namely a practice that is the opposite of what the [Gang of Four](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) recommend. (I am thinking where an iterator pattern is called for, but the programmer uses, say, a numeric index instead. However, I can also imagine idiomatic code that would fall into an anti-pattern.)

If you're looking for a more generic adjective, then perhaps *atypical*, *unconventional*, or *egregious* might suit.

Comment: I don't think you can just say *egregious code* by itself the way you could say [*ugly*](http://thesaurus.com/browse/ugly?s=t) or [*awkward*](http://thesaurus.com/browse/clumsy?s=t).

Comment: I was guessing a bit at the OP's underlying question, and believe the OP is looking for code that is not written in a conventional manner. I had the etymology of *egregious* in mind ("out of the herd"). In contrast, *ugly* is an attribute apart from the social dimension.

Comment: I recall from "The C Programming Language" (also called K&R) an example about copying a string. The code was something like `while (a*++) p* = a*;` Understanding the code entailed knowledge that strings were null terminated; knowledge that the inside of a while loop continued until the expression evaluated was 0; and knowledge of pointer arithmetic. K&R's comment acknowledged that it was cryptic, but also admonished the reader to become familiar with it, because it was a standard practice. Here's a case where the code is both idiomatic and ugly.

Comment: Hey, what’s so ugly about `while (*dst++ = *src++);` anyway? That’s what we call ***elegant***, not ugly. ☺

Comment: Touché, @tchrist. Because the OP has been reticent about describing idiomatic, we may only conclude that the opposite is non-idiomatic. (Elegant, ugly, or awkward are probably orthogonal. I'm still pulling for anti-pattern.) BTW, if you have K&R handy, would you be so kind as to pull their commentary about `while (*dst++ = *src++)`? And thanks for cleaning up the example.

Comment: *Anti-pattern* refers to a common use of code that actually has negative consequences that users are not aware of when they write it. I believe the OP is looking for a term that would describe a unique, unconventional use of code.

Comment: Alas, @Carolyn, part of the problem is that I'm not really sure what the OP means. I would offer that his or her use of *idiomatic* may include "negative consequences that users are not aware of when they write it." I gave an example of an iterator pattern; one can imagine an idiomatic usage where instead of using a Java-supplied iterator, a free-spirited programmer could use a goto and a numeric index. Wouldn't this unique, unconventional use of code be a quintessential anti-pattern?

Comment: I should clarify: I didn't mean to take issue with the negative consequences, but rather with the code's uniqueness. A unique implementation cannot be an anti-pattern, because one implementation does not a pattern make.

Comment: I'm very late to this thread but I feel like I have something useful to say. I wouldn't consider all non-idiomatic code an anti-pattern. There are many things that aren't considered the common practice that are still not technically an anti-pattern. i.e. doesn't result in negative consequences nor have a more "effective" solution. For example, and the reason I am on this thread: Using parenthesis for a return statement in Javascript. This is non-idiomatic, egregious, or at the very least, weird, but I wouldn't consider it an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest "uncharacteristic", "atypical", or possibly "foreign".

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me, all idioms aside, that all we really need here to describe good old straightforward code is to describe it as standard code.

"While Frank wrote idiomatic code that no one could understand, Harry wrote standard code, much easier to follow."

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention code, you might consider using the word **longhand**.

*You could express that loop idiomatically using a standard algorithm instead of writing it out longhand.*

Answer (score -1):

Based on the fact that this question was migrated from programmers.stackexchange and the fact that the question says "as in idiomatic code", I assume the OP means idiomatic in the sense of "structured" and/or "natural" (i.e. as in http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/84102/what-is-idiomatic-code)

For this reason I would suggest either **unnatural-looking** code (since code is rarely read-out) or even more simply **unidiomatic** code.